# Php 5.6 unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, zend-framework, php-5.6

I have a valid wildcard CA Certificate for my sites:

1. myapp.example.com
2. qamyapp.example.com

I need consume a rest service using php 5.6 curl.

When try to execute php curl calling qamyapp.example.com, show the next error:

```
*   Trying xx.xxx.xxx.xx...
* Connected to qamyapp.example.com (xx.xxx.xxx.xx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: 
ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

But when curl call myapp.example.com work fine.

How a can update the ca-certificates.crt file.

Comment: Are you using the same domain name locally as the real live one? Remember certificates only work if the domain names match that on the certificate

Comment: I've updated the question. I see that the problem is only when curl call qamyapp.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. In qamyapp.example.com server, is necesary concat to certificate.crt file, the content of bundle.crt file, to NGinx.